# Systematic one-size-fits-all approach to solving lagrangian optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I often have to solve constrained optimization problems, where I have to maximize a function $O(x)$ (**not necessarily linear!**) s.t. constraints $g(x)=$, and so I formulate the lagrangian

$$L=O(x)+\lambda g(x)$$

I then find all the derivatives:
$$\begin {align}
& L_{x_1}=O_{x_1}(x)+\lambda g_{x_1}(x)\\
&L_{x_2}=O_{x_2}(x)+\lambda g_{x_2}(x)\\
&...\\
&g(x)=0
\end {align}$$

**My approach then, is to just mess around alot with this equations until I find a solution. The result is that if the equations are complex, I'm basically just messing around for a long time, not knowing what I'm doing, until I stumble upon the solution by accident.**

Is there a more systematic way of solving them, so that you always find the solution?

**EDIT:** Let me clarify, **I am only talking about problems for which there is a closed form solution**. My problem is only one of time-efficiency. i.e. I always find the solution after a while, it's just that it takes much longer than I feel it would take if I approached the problem more systematically.

Comment: Solving nonlinear equations symbollically is a huge research area, see for example the field of [Computer Algebra Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system#Mathematics_used_in_computer_algebra_systems). If you need only approximate solutions, [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is helpful. But, as far as I know at least, there's no fast, universally applicable method of solving these kind of systems of nonlinear equations, even for relatively simple systems

Comment: So, you want a systematic method of solving a (determined) system of non-linear (algebraic) equations?  And by "solving," I presume you want explicit closed-form solutions?  I don't think there is such a thing.

Comment: (I was typing my comment at the same time as eepperly16.) Just as an example, although there is a solution to, say, $\cos(x) = x$, there is no explicit closed form (in terms of elementary functions of real numbers) -- and that's just one equation of one variable.  Systems are far worse.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Let me clarify. I am talking in this case only about systems of equations **that do have an analytic solution**. The type of problems I am talking about are relatively simple. It's not that I can't find a solution, it's just that it takes much longer than I feel is necessary.